# Linux Mint Cinnamon Crashes when attempt dual monitor

Tags: linux, linux-mint, nvidia-graphics-card

I have two NVIDIA GTX 750ti installed each with a monitor connected via DVI. The system works fine with just one monitor enabled. However when I user nvidia-settings to enable the second monitor connected to the second GPU, and restart. I get Cinnamon has crashed and I'm in fallback mode.

I'm using the nvidia-current driver

Am I missing something? Everything works fine with 1 monitor but enabling both causes a crash.

Thanks.